# Why does pjsua build shows error after Setting Windows(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) as Linker-> Subystem property in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sdl-2, pjsua2, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I tried compiling pjproject-2.9 [as per the doc](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows) on Windows 10 x64. I tried the following commands. All ran successfully
(i) ./configure (ii) make && make install

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. For building the projects, I followed the procedure given in the above document for VS 2015:

1. opened pjproject-vs14.sln solution file ---> Set pjsua as Startup Project  ---> Set Win32 as the platform ---> Select Debug or Release build ---> Build the project.

Created a empty config_site.h file in pjproject/pjlib/include/pj

I have made the following changes in the pjsua property:
1. Configuration Properties --> General-->Windows SDK Version 10.0.18362.0
    Configuration Properties --> General-->Platform Toolset Visual Studio 2017(v141)
    Project Defaults--> Configuration Type --> Application(.exe)
    Project Defaults--> Use of MFC --> Use Standard Windows Libraries
    Project Defaults--> Character Set --> Use Multi-Byte Character Set
    Project Defaults--> Common Language Runtime Support --> No common language runtime support

2. VC++ Directories --> Include Directories --> (my sdl2 include path and python include path)
   VC++ Directories --> Library Directories --> (python libs path)
3. C/C++ --> General --> (addded SDL2 include path)
4. Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories --> ( added sdl2 libx86 path)
   Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies --> (added SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib )
   Linker --> System --> Subsystem --> Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)
   Linker --> Advanced -->Target Machine --> Not Set
5. pjsua --> Build Dependencies --> Project Dependencies --> Selected All

When i set  Linker --> System --> Subsystem --> Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) it is build successfully. But i need to build this as Windows(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) it shows me the error.

Note: followed this [link](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/setting-up-sdl2-with-visual-studio-2015/) to set the properties for SDL2. I also went through other links like wikihow..everwhere it is mentioned to use Windows(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) only. I need to build this with Windows(/SUBSYSTEM: WINDOWS) only

These are the errors i got:

````
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main_getcmdline    pjsua   ...\pjproject-2.9\pjsip-apps\build\SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj)   1   
LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  pjsua   ...\pjproject-2.9\pjsip-apps\bin\pjsua-i386-Win32-vc14-Release.exe  1```

Please Note: I added/changed property one by one and generated a build. To see which of these is creating the error. only after changing from CONSOLE(/SUBSYSTEM: CONSOLE) to WINDOWS(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS), I got those error. 

Every time before pjsua build, i do pjsua clean. Still, I get these errors

All these error are linker related. Is there any property I have to change?
````

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27SDL_main.27.22_...

Comment: @HansPassant, they haven't mentioned about **Windows(/SUBSYSTEM: WINDOWS)** errors there. Also in that link, they haven't mentioned that SDL2 is supported in windows 10. Is that what caused those errors?

Comment: @HansPassant I have confirmed with SDL wiki that sdl2 supports windows 10. Do u have any other idea about this error?